# How to remove special charactor in Gsheet Query function?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get phone number located on Query2 sheet column D. I am trying to get it on base of city name. City name in Query1 sheet and Query2 sheet is same. and its working with all other cities. But in last city there is some special character it giving some problem.

Please help me that how to remove special character or how to work with special character.

```
=QUERY(Query2!A13:D26, "Select D WHERE A = '"=REGEXREPLACE(A14,"[^A-Za-z]+","")"'")
```

Comment: please share a dummy sheet showing your data layout and the special characters in question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Query2!A13:D26, 
"select D 
 where A = '"&REGEXREPLACE(A14,"[^A-Za-z]+", )&"'")
```